# descifrar un elemento previamente cifrado de la base de datos con mySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sha1

Cuando guardo un elemento password en mi base de datos, lo guardo con

**sha1(...)** y esto se guarda, por ejemplo, si pongo *hola*, de la siguiente forma : *fc1815288c56c87a05ef3cfd10738015bc5c1129*

```
<?php 
$conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','pruebas');

$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$apellido=$_POST['apellido'];
$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$password=sha1($_POST['password']);

$sql="INSERT into usuarios (nombre,apellido,usuario,password)
        values ('$nombre','$apellido','$usuario','$password')";
echo mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
?>
```

¿Mi pregunta es, como puedo desde una pagina web, recuperar este valor descifrado, es decir, *hola*?

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos el método SHA1 al igual que otros me ayuda a crear una salida con una combinación **alfanumérica** o hasheada.

Entre los mas comunes tenemos a MD5(), SHA1, SALT(); sin embargo el mas recomendable es usar **password_hash()**; los resultados de datos que son hasheados no se recuperan a su forma original lo que hace internamente por ejemplo PHP es comparar le hash interno con el ingresado por el usuario.

Modo de uso:

```
$contrasenia = password_hash("alfredo", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Ahora a través del método verify(), comprobare que el hash ingresado corresponda al que esta almacenado en la BD

```
$password_usuario_ingresa = $_POST['password'];
$coincidencia = password_verify($password_usuario_ingresa, $contrasenia);
```

Ahoara simplemente con un if compruebo si coinciden ambos valores

```
if($coincidencia) {
 echo "Los valores coinciden";
} else {
 echo "Los valores no coinciden";
}
```

Saludos espero haberme explicado.